# Can't find package Roboto font

Tags: packages, miktex

To get things to look according to the house style defined by the university they've created a latex style. I'm trying to implement this but get the error: **File `roboto.sty' not found. \RequirePackage**

Although I can work with LaTeX, I have no understanding of .cls or .bst files which are apparently used for the styling of a document. The house style file has worked for other students and I find it strange why it doesn't work for me.

Does anybody have an idea why Texstudio (and Miktex) can compile the document? I thought Miktex would automatically install the package if it wasn't installed yet?

The house style can be downloaded from the website from the university: [TU Delft Report style](https://intranet.tudelft.nl/fileadmin/Files/medewerkersportal/mc/huisstijl/Downloads/report_style.zip)

Comment: Check if the package is installed with MiKTeX Package Manager. If it is not, install it. Next, in any case run from the command line `updmap.exe`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've had a look at the package manager but I can't find a package named Roboto...

Comment: You can use roboto fonts without loading any roboto.sty file. If you have roboto in your system fonts, then try to compile your document with xelatex and lualatex, with `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{roboto}`. But we won't be very helpful without any MWE.

Comment: @Yorian: Your distribution is not up-to-date; you should synchronise the  repository ( menu `Repository` in MPM): roboto was packages on 22/09. You can filter the list of packages by `names`.

Comment: `yes | sudo apt install fonts-roboto` and `yes | sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` resolved it for me.